# The default exit button of an electron.js app doesn't work for me

Tags: electron

ok so I have been cracking my head over this problem for the last 2 days.
The default exit button of an electron.js app doesn't work.
Whenever I run my app and I click on the exit button, it doesn't show any error in the terminal and doesn't close the app either.

So far, these are the code snippets I have used:

```
// functions I used
app.on('window-all-closed') {
 }
app.on('close') {

}

// the code inside the functions I used
_____________________________________

   app.destroy()
_____________________________________

   app.exit()

_____________________________________

   app = null;
```

And I haven't used any HTML code since I am loading the URL of the page I want to make as an app like this:

```
function createWindow () {
  const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 720,
    height: 600,
    icon:'assets/icons/win/icon.png',
  })

  win.loadURL('https://insert-link')
  win.removeMenu()
  win.on("closed", () => mainWindow.destroy());
}

const { app } = require('electron')
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.once('window-all-closed', function() {
      app.quit().then(app.destroy())
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: When you say "default exit button" what do you mean? Do you mean the Electron window's close button?

Comment: @Joshua Yes the window's exit button
Not anything that's related to HTML

Comment: i'm pretty sure `app.quit()` doesn't return a promise so your code in `window-all-closed` will crash. And `app.destroy()` isn't a function. Also, this code will crash since `mainWindow` isn't defined: `win.on("closed", () => mainWindow.destroy());`.

Comment: hmm well, I changed mainWindow.destroy() to win.destroy and it still doesn't work

Comment: If you have native modules running, those will prevent electron from properly exitting: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20425